# How CodeIgniter url work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to php so it did not seem like a good idea to use the framework.
I want to create my own framework from strach.
I want to open php class with a url like what codeigniter do. 
I want to use urls like index.php / MyClass instead "get" index.php? class = MyClass.
 how can I achieve that?

Comment: hello its good decision you have desire to develop your own framework but its not a work of toddlers first make sure you have core knowledge of php and oop then you are able to develop your own framework.

Comment: Type "jream mvc" in yt search form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made good decision to develop your framework . This is known as Routing or URL Rewriting . You can learn this at [URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). For a complete framework , You have to learn about

1. Template System
2. Query Builder etc

I suggest you to learn Codeigniter framework for better understanding of PHP framework